# IOS application lifecycle: When are the view or view controllers called on application startup?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

When I generate a new application in xcode, there is a ViewController.swift file and AppDelegate.swift as well as a main.storyboard.

With respect to the MVC model, can someone explain to me how this application initiates the "View" in this simple app? I am unable to find any lines of code within AppDelegate that initiate either the main.storyboard or the ViewController.swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be asking this is to misunderstand what AppDelegate is for. AppDelegate is there to receive important events in the application lifecycle, and for you to act on these events if you want. But these events are generated within the UIApplication code:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/

A whole lot of framework code is included in your App but remains hidden (no source shown, all precompiled, automatically included libraries); you have to spend substantial time reading the Apple dev docs to understand your entry points.

Within Xcode, you set one View Controller as the "is initial view controller" attribute within the Attributes Inspector. The UIApplication startup code parses your Main.storyboard file, looks for this attribute, instantiates this view controller for you, and presents it for display as the root view controller by connecting it to the App's UIWindow. Then you are free to override any of the View Controller lifecycle events you need, implement as many @IBActions as you want, work with your @IBOutlets and in general go about your iOS-based event-driven programming.

Also, a ViewController manages a set of views (UIViews), but it is not a view itself.

Also, MVC is a repeating pattern *within* any GUI-based application; it is not *the* governing pattern, because it says nothing about how an App starts up and shuts down, which varies greatly between operating environments.

So it seems you're still in somewhat of a haze and need to do a lot of reading. It begs the question -- what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Another thing to add to this is that in the project inspector -> Info you can set the "Main storyboard interface name" which by default in new projects is "Main" that is the storyboard file that will get instantiated but the App when it is ready.

Comment: Thanks Good Doug, you definitely clarified this whole problem. I guess I just didn't realize how much of the initialization of classes is done behind the scenes. I am trying to understand the xcode app development frameworks moving from javafx game development, where I had to initialize everything. Whereas in ios, things like UIApplication are initialized already. I suppose that is the beauty of ios development, but it definitely left some gaps in the logic when I was going through the code.